# NDSolve 3D Poisson PDE (cylindrical coordinates)

Tags: differential-equations

I try to model the threedimensional heating problem of a flat cylinder which is heated along the circumference and cooled along the face side. The temperature `u[r, \[CurlyPhi], z]==u[r, \[CurlyPhi], -z]` is symmetric.

Trying to solve this heating porblem in cylindrical coordinates

```
T = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[r, \[CurlyPhi], z], {r, \[CurlyPhi], z}, "Cylindrical"]== 
NeumannValue[-100, r == 30]  (* Qin *)
+ NeumannValue[ (u[r, \[CurlyPhi], z] - 300), z == 10]  (* Qout*)
+ NeumannValue[ 0, z == 0] (* symmetry  z\[Equal]0*)
,PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[r, \[CurlyPhi], z], \[CurlyPhi] == 2 \[Pi], Function[x, x - 2 \[Pi]]]},
u  (* Temperatur u[r,\[CurlyPhi],z] *)
, {r, 0, 30}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 0, 10}, Method -> "FiniteElement"]
```

I get several error messages (`TetGenDetectIntersectingFacets::tetpts: The points {{0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.588235},{0.,0.,1.17647},<<45>>,{0.,1.1424,7.05882},{0.,1.1424,7.64706},<<3070>>} could not be set to the TetGen instance.`)

wheras the result

```
Plot[Table[T[r, 0, z], {z, 0, 10}], {r, 0, 30},GridLines -> {None, {300}}]
```

[image]

seems to be plausible.

What's wrong with my code?
How can I avoid the error messages?

Thanks!

Comment: No warning in _v11.3_. The output of `Plot` is the same as yours.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks, it seems to be an issue of my Mathematica version 11.0.1.